# Редактировать профиль Laravel

Tags: laravel

Пользователь редактирует свой профиль, пароль он не меняет, как записать в таблицу изменяемые значения не трогая поле пароля в базе ?

Comment: Как вы пароль хэшируете?

Comment: Не беспокойтесь по этому поводу, Eloquen достаточно умен, чобы обновлять только те записи, которые нужно.